# Display only the largest count in a group by statment

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to display only the largest group in this group by statement;

```
SELECT COUNT(type) AS booking, type FROM booking b, room r WHERE r.rno = b.rno AND r.hno = b.hno GROUP BY type;
```

I modified it so we get this query response now you can see group double is larger then family.

BOOKING TYPE

---

```
     5 double
     2 family
```

I know there is a HAVING keyword you can add in order display only a count compared to a number so I could do COUNT(type) HAVING > 2 or similar but that's not very dynamic and that would only work in this instance because I know the two amounts.

Comment: Please specify your database version - the answer depends on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a `having` statement that does this.  But you can use `rownum` with a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (SELECT COUNT(type) AS booking, type
      FROM booking b join
           room r
           on r.rno = b.rno AND r.hno = b.hno
      GROUP BY type
      order by count(type) desc
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: @JeffreyKemp . . . That didn't make sense, did it.  I changed it to what I intended.

Comment: that's better :) - deleting my comment

Answer (score 3):

ORDER BY COUNT(type) DESC LIMIT 1

Answer (score 1):

Just order your query..

order by booking desc

regards

Answer (score 1):

TRY this

```
SELECT COUNT(type) AS booking, type FROM booking b, room r WHERE r.rno = b.rno AND r.hno = b.hno ORDER BY type DESC LIMIT 1
```